# Linear model not achieving distribution width

Tags: regression

I'm training a linear model and get an R2 of 0.07 in training, 0.06 in test set. While not 'great' in my application (trading) I hear this is reasonable.

The distribution of the target (top image) below is a lot wider tailed than what my predictions get (bottom). Making it a lot less practically useful as a trade signal entry.

Is there a way to force the linear model to learn more about the wider part of the tails and achieve a wider distribution?

[image]

Comment: Not sure in your field, but such an R squared is pretty low and signaling, in my experience, a useless model.

Comment: This is a direct consequence of *regression to the mean* (which, as a purely mathematical phenomenon, is unavoidable).  In the extreme limit of $R^2=0,$ your predictions will be constant.  You can reproduce the full width of the target distribution only when $R^2 = 1$ or when you are adding gratuitous noise to your predictions.  *Any* forcing of the model to recreate the spread will be tantamount to injecting such noise.  That can be useful for making realistic *simulations* of the target, but not for accurately predicting it.

Comment: Take a look at the links in [Canonical duplicate for "Why do predictions vary less than observations?"](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5567/1352)